# npm install if package.json was modified

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package.json

TL;DR: Is there a way to have `npm install` run automatically before running any npm script if your `package.json` has been modified?

### Problem Scenario

You pull or checkout a branch that updated `package.json`. You run `npm run my-script`. `my-script` depends on a package that has newly been added to `package.json`. `my-script` fails. You wonder why. Before flipping over your desk you run `npm install` just to be sure. `my-script` runs successfully. You don't need a new desk.

I know that build / task runner tools like `gradle` make sure that your dependencies are up-to-date before running a task. I has always been a (minor) pain point that `npm` doesn't do it. I stumbled over two solutions that I don't particluarly like.

### Non-Ideal Solution: make

Instead of relying on npm scripts in your `package.json` to run commands you use `make` and make use of its integrated dependency tracking with the following trick:

```
# Smart install: Only executes if package.json's
# modification date is later than node_module's

node_modules: package.json
    npm install
    @rm -f node_modules/.modified
    @touch -m node_modules/.modified

install: node_modules
```

Source: https://mattandre.ws/2016/05/make-for-hipsters/

The problem is that you know have to rely on `make` to run scripts and lose certain advantages of npm scripts such as conveniently referring to other scripts and running scripts in parallel (`npm-run-all`). It's also harder to work with others if they don't know `make` or have problems running it (Windows). It's an archaic tool outside of the node/npm ecosystem and too costly just for this smart install advantage.

### Non-Ideal Solution: Git hook

Another way is to add a `post-merge` git hook.

The problem is that this solution is local to the repository and can't be easily shared. `npm install` will only be run automatically on git merges. When you change `package.json` in any other way you still have to remember running `npm install`. Admittedly, that's a minor point in practice. Nonetheless, it would be nice to never have to think about running `npm install` at all when you want to run a script.

Source: https://davidwalsh.name/git-hook-npm-install-package-json-modified

### Ideal Solution

I'd like to define my `package.json` in a way similar to:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "pre-run": "npm-smart-install",
    "my-script": "…"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "npm-smart-install": "1.0.0"
  }
}
```

`npm-smart-install` is a hypothetical npm package that I wish existed. `pre-run` is a hypothetical npm-scripts lifecycle hook. When I run `npm run my-script` and `package.json` has been modified since the last run of any script, run `npm install` before running `my-script`.

To repeat: Is there a way to have `npm install` run automatically before running any npm script if your `package.json` has been modified without relying on tools outside the npm ecosystem?

Comment: Your hypothetical package might not be very hard to implement yourself. You could generate a hash digest of `package.json` upon the first install and then use it in subsequent installs to check if the file changed.  [This](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-changed) looks like it does something similar.

Comment: Also, why not just run `npm install` before any script? If everything is there with the correct version then it won't do anything.

Comment: This would delay the running of each script.

Comment: This sounds like a problem [NPM's tink](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/178027064160/next-generation-package-management/amp) is hoping to solve (albeit that's years away).

Comment: Maybe we should make a "npmi-run-all" that does this. We could store the hash in the `tmpDir` provided by `fs`

Comment: I'm almost done with the package. Trying to figure out how I can execute it like in your ideal solution scenario.

Comment: Here's corrected link to [NPM's tink](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://blog.npmjs.org/post/178027064160/next-generation-package-management) blog post

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay so I'm done with the package. [Here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/install-changed) it is. You can use it exactly the same way you specified in your ideal scenario. Just `npm install install-changed` and add it to a custom script, like `pre-run` in your example. It should figure out whether or not it needs to `npm install` and does so if it needs to.

```
 {
  "scripts": {
    "pre-run": "install-changed",
    "my-script": "…"
  },
```

You can also do this programatically but I don't think you're going to need this.

```
let installChanged = require('install-changed')

let isModified = installChanged.watchPackage()
```

The function above does exactly the same thing, additonally it also returns a boolean value which you might find useful.

Comment: Good work! I just wish npm had an integrated 'prerun' hook. As it is now, I'd have to either write `"my-script": "npm run prerun && …"` or `"premy-script": "install-changed", "my-script": "…"`.

Comment: instead of `packagehash.txt` it should use the current version of `package.json` from the git history

Comment: There's a fork of `install-changed` called `package-changed`, it's basically the same thing but is more flexible, allows you to run any command when package.json deps/devDeps change. I then forked this fork and named it `lockfile-changed`, since it instead just creates hash of `yarn.lock` contents. It is all about yarn. I recommend using `package-changed` unless you really want it to be based on a yarn.lock+use yarn. If you use my package, it might have bugs. I haven't tested it quite yet.

Comment: @ninesalt Great, it worked for my project, but unfortunately, i am getting an error when I execute the same with the pipeline "pre-run: Failed to exec pre-run script"

Answer (score 6):

You can create a custom script that will run your smart install.

*smart-install.sh file*

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

changedFiles="$(git diff-tree -r --name-only --no-commit-id ORIG_HEAD HEAD)"

checkForChangedFiles() {
    echo "$changedFiles" | grep --quiet "$1" && eval "$2"
}

packageJsonHasChanged() {
  echo "Changes to package.json detected, installing updates"
  npm i
}

checkForChangedFiles package.json packageJsonHasChanged
```

Then if you have husky you can add that to the post-checkout hook or any hook you like. If you don't have husky, you can also add it directly to the scripts which essentially do the same thing.

*.huskyrc file*

```
{
  "hooks": {
    "post-checkout": "npm run smart-install"
  }
}
```

*package.json file*

```
"scripts": {
  ...
  "smart-install": "bash ./bin/smart-install.sh",
}
```

Either way it's a good idea to create a npm script to run `smart-install`

Comment: similar to yarnhook: https://github.com/frontsideair/yarnhook

Answer (score 4):

You can also do this using husky post-checkout hook by adding this piece of code there.

```
if [ $(git diff HEAD@{1}..HEAD@{0} -- "package.json" | wc -l) -gt 0 ];
then
  npm i
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

One easy solution is to use git diff and grep

```
git diff --name-only HEAD HEAD~1 | grep package.json && npm install
```

this command first check difference between latest commit and last commit, from which it will list the files that are changed in latest.After that grep is used to find "package.json" in that list.If it finds that in the list it will run "npm install" either it won't.

Comment: how can we add this step to the automatic build?

Answer (score 1):

Like other answers, but I think simpler because it's one line of shell script in package.json:

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "install-if-needed": "[ package.json -nt node_modules ] && npm install && touch node_modules",
        "my-script": "npm run install-if-needed && ..."
    }
}
```

or, basically equivalent:

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "install-if-needed": "[ package.json -nt node_modules ] && npm install && touch node_modules",
        "premy-script": "npm run install-if-needed",
        "my-script": "..."
    }
}
```

You'll have to either inline `npm run install-if-needed` or have a `pre...` script for each script that needs it -- I don't know any other way to have it run before multiple other scripts.

Explanation: `install-if-needed` checks the modification times on `package.json` and `node_modules`.  If `node_modules` is newer, it does nothing; otherwise it runs `npm install`.  The final `touch node_modules` is necessary because `npm install` may itself change the package.json modification time (if it is correcting whitespace in package.json for example).

Comment: Last modified time of node_modules is not going to be as reliable as a hash of npm/yarn lockfile :/